# Make frame disappear when it is not in focus

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, frame, focusout

I'm trying to make a frame disappear when it is not in focus, as in, if the mouse is clicked anywhere but the frame, then the frame should disappear.

Like what a pop up menu does, although I don't want to use a pop up menu.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')

b = Button(root, text='Show Frame',command=lambda: showlabel())
b.pack()
l = Frame(width=200,height=200,bg='black')
l.bind("<FocusOut>", l.pack_forget())


def showlabel():
    l.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `l.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: l.pack_forget())` ? But i dont think a frame can get focus

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Ya that is because i dont think there is a way to toggle focus on frames, though you can say `l.focus_force()` then try this and it would work.

Comment: how do i use that?

Comment: Im not sure if there is a proper way to do so.

Comment: @CoolCloud: yes, you can toggle focus on a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<FocusOut>` refers to keyboard focus. It sounds like that's not what you mean, however, since frames don't typically have keyboard focus.

If you are trying to emulate a popup window or message box, one way would be to add a *grab* on the window, and a binding that detects when you click outside the window.

A *grab* is a way to focus all events to a window and it's children. This is handy because you don't want the user to interact with widgets outside of your popup window while it is visible. For example, you don't want a click on the `Show Frame` button to open another window if the window is already visible.

Once you've created the frame, you can call `grab_set` on the frame. You can then add a binding on the frame, and the binding will fire even when the user clicks outside the frame. In the binding you can check to see whether the binding is inside or outside, and hide the window if the click is outside.

The solution looks something like this:

```
def showlabel():
    def dismiss(event):
        if not ((0 <= event.x <= l.winfo_width()) and (0 <= event.y <= l.winfo_height())):
            l.grab_release()
            l.pack_forget()

    l.pack(pady=20)
    l.bind("<1>", dismiss)
    l.grab_set()
```

This would be better to implement as a class, but this gives a general idea.

Comment: what if ```def showlabel``` is a method of a class, how would I implement your answer

Comment: and the frame is an instance of the class

Comment: @coderoftheday: I wouldn't make `showlabel` a method of an existing class. I would create a new class that is responsible for creating the frame and then adding the binding.

Comment: so should i pass event from the button into the new class

Comment: @coderoftheday: there are many ways to do it. The point is, however you want to implement it, use `grab_set` to have the popuip get all of the events, and then create a binding on a mouse click to dismiss the dialog when the user clicks outside.